# Is there a wildcard operator/character in SharePoint Designer that can map one list item in one list to All items in a separate list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, custom-list

I have created a list where I need a one-to-many workflow interaction with another list. The workflow is manual start, within list one, and on item select it would copy that item over to list 2. However I would need that item to be connected to every list item in list 2. Ex.

```
List 1             List2
Item 1A            Item 2A : Item 1A 
                   Item 2B : Item 1A
                   Item 2C : Item 1A
```

Is there a operator needed, or could this be accomplished this using the create item action?

Answer (score 0):

In the SharePoint Designer, mapping one list item in one list to all items in another list is not available.

As a workaround, you could use lookup column to achieve this.